# How to measure how long a thread will exactly take from new to end in java

Tags: java, java-threads

**The questions:**

1. is there anyway to get the exact time a thread will take from new to end?
2. why do the results in each time have huge differences (see code below)?

**The code:**

```
public void process2(){
    final long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Thread newT = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
            // System.out.println((end-start));

            for (int i = 1, sum = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
                sum += i;
            }
        }
    });
    long end1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("new thread time took :" + (end1 - start));
    newT.start();

    int i = 0;
    while (newT.isAlive()) {
        i++;
    }

    long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("total time:" + (end - start));
    System.out.println("judge count:" + i);

}
```

Comment: Try google searching for "context switching" and "software threads"

Comment: You are also measuring the Main thread time, the While loop which is continuously checking the is Alive  steals CPU cycles, instead you can use join

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It is usually more relevant to measure the the time of execution, that is the time taken to execute `run()` method. This time will generally be similar between different runs.
2. The creation on a new `Thread` object is rather costly, and depends on currently available resources of the system, which is why there can be big differences in time taken between `Thread` creation and its execution. What's more, is that before destruction of a thread, there is a clean-up process that can also take up a significant amount of time.

One ways to optimize the thread management time (creations/destruction) is to use a `ThreadPool` or an `ExecutorService`. See Oracle [concurrency tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

You have cooked up a very bad example for measuring.

First, creating a new thread with new is *dead cheap* (its a plain java object). But you include actually class loading time for you anonymous Runnable. This will involve I/O, so its *to be expected* that execution time varies quite a bit, especially on the first run.

Then you are measuring time in milliseconds. But the system time does not necessarily have actual millisecond resolution (read the javadocs of System.currentTimeMillis). Also, what you are attempting to measure will most of the time execute in *less* than a millisecond.

Your Runnable has no observable side effects, so the JIT will probably just optimize the entire code away after a short warmup. After a few runs the runnable may actually not take any time at all.

The you are *polling* to determine when the other thread ends. Thats keeping the CPU (well one core if you have more than one) busy doing nothing useful. For a single core machine this means an average of 50% of the time is spent doing nothing but checking if the thread is alive. Depending on how the OS scheduler runs the threads this is another source of variation.

All in all you have cooked up a *microbenchmark* and you have stepped in all the most common pitfalls that microbenchmarks can suffer in java. Benchmarking in java requires some care, or you will measure anything but not the performance of the code you actaully want to measure. There are benchmarking frameworks and also excellent articles on how to properly benchmark in java, as well as a ton of related questions here on SO. Make use of these resources.

Comment: deep analysis,Thanks